# ArrayAdapter returns a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am using a spinner that has data to be filled in by an Array Adapter. The code returns a run-time error caused by `NullPointerException`. I have declared the spinner and initialized it in on create method.The error still persists. Please help me solve the bug.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

Button btnCfg, btnConnect, btnClear, btnUpload, btnDownload, btnLoad_on, btnLoad_off;
TextView txtSelectDayTitle;
Spinner spinnerDay;
private String[] arraySpinner;
private Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Automatic Day Picker
    String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM");
    if (from != null && from.equals("DaysOfTheWeek"))
    {
        this.arraySpinner = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    }
    //Initialization of variables
    spinnerDay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDay);
    btnCfg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCfg);
    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
    btnLoad_on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad_on);
    btnLoad_off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad_off);
    txtSelectDayTitle = findViewById(R.id.txtSelectDayTitle);


    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date d = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = null;
    try
    {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(d);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String dayOfTheWeek = dayFormat.format(d);
    txtSelectDayTitle.setText(dayOfTheWeek);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerDay.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Logcat**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3741)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3728)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:163)
    at com.example.itimer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
```

Comment: Can you provide your logcat error

Comment: the exception stacktrace will show what is null in your code. Either check it yourself or post here.

Comment: *Analyze my Code and help me solve the bug* - hmmm....

Comment: am just a newbie. i have never used the platform before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `if (from != null && from.equals("DaysOfTheWeek"))` check if this condition is `true`. `arraySpinner` only initialized if it is `true`

Comment: `Analyze my Code and help me solve the bug.` this does not work that way on StackOverflow. If you want somebody to `Analyze my Code and help me solve the bug.`, you can hire a developer somewhere. Or you can *ask people here to help you fixing your code*. Please be more kind, and instead of giving orders like `Analyze my Code and help me solve the bug.` ask people to help.

Comment: sorry for my approach. And thanks for correcting that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this part of your code is getting initialized,

```
String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM");
if (from != null && from.equals("DaysOfTheWeek"))
{
    this.arraySpinner = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

}
```

Confirm if arraySpinner is not null. If it is null then this is causing that null pointer exception.

Comment: Yah appears that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply because you have a **null** value of `arraySpinner` variable for the Adapter.

You should always initialize the array whenever you need to give it to your Adapter.

You can use one of the following options:

**First option**, always initialize the array:

```
String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM");
if (from == null) {
  // initialize the array when found nothing
  arraySpinner = new String[];

} else if(from.equals("DaysOfTheWeek")) {
    arraySpinner = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

} else {
  // initialize the array when incorrect from string found.
  arraySpinner = new String[];
}
```

**Second option**, crash the program when there is no `from` string:

```
String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM");
if (from == null) {
  throw new RuntimeException("No extra found!");
  return;
}

// if incorrect from string found
if (!from.equals("DaysOfTheWeek")) {
  throw new RuntimeException("No DaysOfTheWeek found!");
  return;
}

 // correct extra for from is found.
 arraySpinner = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
```